# How to get a time interval between two strings?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I have 2 times stored in separate strings in the form of `H:M` I need to get the difference between these two and be able to tell how much minutes it equals to. I was trying `datetime` and `timedelta`, but I'm only a beginner and I don't really understand how that works. I'm getting attribute errors everytime.

So I have a and b times, and I have to get their difference in minutes.

**E.G**. `if a = 14:08 and b= 14:50` the difference should be 42

How do I do that in python in the simplest way possible? also, in what formats do I need to use for each step?

Comment: Where does the 4 comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the difference is 42, not 4 (since there are 42 minutes between 14:08 and 14:50).

If the times always contains of a 5 character length string, than it's reasonably easy.

```
time1 = '14:08'
time2 = '15:03'
hours = int(time2[:2]) - int(time1[:2])
mins  = int(time2[3:]) - int(time1[3:])
print(hours)
print(mins)
print(hours * 60 + mins)
```

Prints:

```
1
-5
55
```

- hours will be the integer value of the left two digits [:1] subtraction of the second and first time
- minutes will be the integer value of the right two digits [3:] subtraction of the second and first time
- This prints 55 ... with your values it prints out 42 (the above example is to show it also works when moving over a whole hour.

Comment: @blhsing correct about [:2], I will fix this, but than hours will be 15-14 = 1, mins = 08-50=-42, hours * 60 + mins = 1 * 60 - 42 = 18, which seems correct.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yeah, It was a typo in the 42's case, I edited it now so others won't get confused

Comment: Note that using fixed indices means that this solution would not work if there is only 1 (or 3 or more) digits in the hours.

Comment: @blhsing I know ... but that's why I put the second line (if the times always contains of a 5 character length string).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

*also the difference is 42 not 4* `50-8==42` I assume that was a typo

```
from datetime import datetime

a,b = "14:08", "14:50"

#convert to datetime
time_a = datetime.strptime(a, "%H:%M")
time_b = datetime.strptime(b, "%H:%M")

#get timedelta from the difference of the two datetimes
delta = time_b - time_a

#get the minutes elapsed
minutes = (delta.seconds//60)%60

print(minutes)
#42
```

Comment: Note that using `strptime` means that this solution would not work if there are more than 24 hours.

Comment: This is good to note, however the assumption was made that he has "2 times". If he had a value above 24 then it would not be an average "HH:MM" time value persay. depends how you're using it. And he did not specify that.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the difference between the `datetime.timedelta` objects created from the given time strings `a` and `b` by subtracting the former from the latter, and use the `total_seconds` method to obtain the time interval in seconds, with which you can convert to minutes by dividing it by 60:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from operator import sub
sub(*(timedelta(**dict(zip(('hours', 'minutes'), map(int, t.split(':'))))) for t in (b, a))).total_seconds() // 60
```

So that given `a = '29:50'` and `b = '30:08'`, this returns:

```
18.0
```